# Dreaded WCF BAD request 400 due to maxReceivedMessageSize still being 65536

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-400

God don't you just love WCF.

I read all possible threads but I am really stuck now.

Here is WCF configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
         <binding name="BaseHttp" 
                  maxBufferSize="4194304" 
                  maxBufferPoolSize="4194304" 
                  maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"  />
      </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior name="TaskServiceBehavior">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
         </behavior>
         <behavior name="">
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="TaskServiceBehavior" name="TaskService">
         <endpoint 
             address="http://www.mysite.com/TableTaskService/TableTaskService.svc" 
             binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BaseHttp" 
             contract="TableTaskService.ITableTaskService" />
         <endpoint 
             address="mex" 
             binding="mexHttpBinding"  
             contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="http://www.mysite.com/TableTaskService/" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
      </service>
   </services>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment>
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
         <add prefix="http://www.mysite.com/" />
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
   </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Now I send a message and get thrown this default exception ( saw in svclog file):

> The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been
>   exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize
>   property on the appropriate binding element.

Now I clearly state that it should be 4mb.

My client code :

```
TableTaskServiceClient client = 
    new TableTaskServiceClient(
          new BasicHttpBinding { MaxBufferSize = 4194304, 
                                 MaxReceivedMessageSize = 4194304 }, 
          new EndpointAddress(GetEndpointAddressString())
    );
```

Yet it throws this 65536 size error at me. Where is it coming from??..

Also does it REALLY matter that client sets up `MaxReceivedMessageSize` to same value as server? I think it would be logical that server was responsible for determining length, not client.

There is also this warning (notice how useful it is in what its saying, that is: no information on element that gets overridden or am I missing something), maybe basichttpbinding is exactly what gets overridden ? but why would that be? anyway:

> [TraceRecord] Severity    Warning
>   TraceIdentifier   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.OverridingDuplicateConfigurationKey.aspx
>   Description   The configuration system has detected a duplicate key in a
>   different configuration scope and is overriding with the more recent
>   value.
>   AppDomain /LM/W3SVC/11/ROOT/TableTaskService-33-1296567
>   Source    System.ServiceModel.Configuration.ServiceBehaviorElementCollection/-851144413
>   ElementName   behavior OldElementLineNumber   0 NewElementLineNumber  0

UPDTE:
reconfigured both service and client :

```
TableTaskServiceClient client = new TableTaskServiceClient(
                        new BasicHttpBinding { 
                            MaxBufferSize = 4194304, 
                            MaxReceivedMessageSize = 4194304,
                            MaxBufferPoolSize=4194304,
                            ReaderQuotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas
                                               {
                                                   MaxArrayLength = 4194304, 
                                                   MaxBytesPerRead = 4194304, 
                                                   MaxDepth = 4194304, 
                                                   MaxNameTableCharCount = 4194304,
                                                   MaxStringContentLength = 4194304
                                               }
                        }, new EndpointAddress(GetEndpointAddressString()));
```

Same error still.

If that is of some interest I am sending a byte[] array of 467000~ length

Answer (score 1):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731325.aspx
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/151753/BlogFeedList.aspx?amid=Andrii-Vasylevskyi&display=Mobile

Try this:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="BaseHttp"
           maxBufferSize="4194304"
           maxBufferPoolSize="4194304"
           maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304">
    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="4194304"
                  maxBytesPerRead="4194304"
                  maxDepth="4194304"
                  maxNameTableCharCount="4194304"
                  maxStringContentLength="4194304"
                  />
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Though some of those settings don't make sense, I simply set them to a large value.

Also, once you get this working I highly suggest you trim down the values, since they're present to prevent [DoS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) on your site.

Comment: Same error . I confirmed a couple of times that this configuration is used in service configuration ( changed to BaseHttp1 , saw error, changed back, service works fine in browser), yet still the same. I believe it should be working.. but it just doesn't.

Comment: Are you configuring both the service and the client?  Cause I'd bet there's a cap setting on the client side too.